# Modify list of parameters in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm creating a batch file that takes an argument followed by a list of filenames. I'd like to pass the list of filenames to another executable within the batch file, but I don't want to also pass the first argument.

Like this:

```
Usage: LaunchTest.bat <config file> files ...
```

Where LaunchTest.bat is something like:

```
SET CFGFILE=%1
@REM The below does not work, because %* still has the CFGFILE value of %1 in it
@REM I thought I could 'shift', which moves %2, etc., down to %1, etc., but it
@REM does not change the values in %*.
@REM Testing.exe expects only the list of files.
Testing.exe %*
```

Any idea how to remove a parameter from %*, or construct an arbitrary-length list of arguments to pass to a command?

Thanks, and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

echo config file: %~1

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "rest_of_line="
for %%a in (%*) do (
    if !.!==. (
        set "rest_of_line=!rest_of_line! %%a"
    )
    set .=.
)
endlocal && (
    set "rest_of_line=%rest_of_line%"
)
echo %rest_of_line%
```

Comment: This works well, and also gives me the option to tweak each argument before passing it along. I don't understand the syntax at all, though (I only have a very basic knowledge of batch file syntax).

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "parms=%*"
CALL SET "parms=%%parms:*%1=%%"
ECHO(%parms:~1%

echo======= Second way


SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "parms=%*"
SET "parms=!parms:*%1=!"
ECHO(%parms:~1%

GOTO :EOF
```

Two ways - with and without `delayedexpansion`.